# Valid not working for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a Javascript function that check the input data and serialize them, the problem is the .valid doesn't work for IE8 but work for IE9 and 10

```
function sendData()
{
var inputData=$("#DataContainer").find(":input");
if(validate&& !inputData.valid()) return;
//some other codes
}
```

in IE9 and 10 the inputData.valid() is 0 i.e. false but for IE8 it is 1 i.e. true and I am wondering why this behaviour for the same set of data? and the result is the actions attached to the function don't work.

Thanks

Comment: You should show the code related to the valid() function.

Comment: Post here `valid()` function

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: the valid is from Unobstrusive JQuery validate and will validate the content of the form depending on the validation enforced on your model. this is MVC

Comment: @SnakeEyes: please see the answer above. hope that help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jack: I think you are using valid() method with IE8 emulator(not true IE8). In IE8 emulator it is making all the field as required field.
First you should validate all your input fields then serialize your data

```
$("#DataContainer").validate({
    onkeyup: function(element) { $(element).valid(); },  // check validation on key up  
    rules: {
        txt_Topic: "required",
        txt_Date: "required"
    },
    message: {
        txt_Topic: "This field is required.",
        txt_Date: "This field is required."
    }
});

// if is valid call functions
if($('form #DataContainer').valid()) {
    sentData();
} 

function sentData() {
    var inputData = $("#DataContainer").serializeObject();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var inputData=$("#DataContainer").find("input");
```